# how to override truncation in gdb

Tags: unix, emacs, gdb

When I print in gdb by running:

```
p cmd.c_str()
```

the result is truncated to 200 characters. is there a way that I can set the default truncation to something higher like 1000 characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [GDB manual](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/documentation/):

#### set print elements number-of-elements

> Set a limit on how many elements
> of an array gdb will print. If gdb is printing a large array, it stops
> printing after it has printed the number of elements set by the set
> print elements command. This limit also applies to the display of
> strings. When gdb starts, this limit is set to 200. Setting
> number-of-elements to zero means that the printing is unlimited.

```
set print elements 2000
```

Will show the first 2000 members of arrays, cstrings.  As the docs say, setting this to zero will allow unlimited display.